# Close Dropdown when I click outside dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on another developer's work and trying to fix an oversight of his. We have a filter system which opens drop-downs with check-boxes via which we can filter a listing grid. However, originally the old dev was using toggleClass so we could only close the drop-down by clicking the same `h3` tag again, meaning one could stack the various drop-downs.

I managed to fix this so that clicking a different filter `h3` tag would close all drop-downs but this wouldn't allow you to anymore close a drop-down by clicking the same `h3` tag again.

I've decided the most user-friendly way to do this is to have a drop-down close when I click anywhere *except* the drop-down.

Based on some similar questions here, I came up with this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".open_filter").removeClass("open_filter");
});

jQuery('.filter-section h3').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('arrow-down');
    if (!jQuery(this).parent().find('.lef-shop-section ul').hasClass('open_filter')){
       jQuery(this).parent().find('.lef-shop-section ul').addClass('open_filter');
    } else {
        $(".open_filter").removeClass("open_filter");
    }
});
```

I'm not the best at jQuery, I am much more comfortable with standard js but as I'm sure you can tell, the above doesn't work, nothing happens at all unless I remove the `$(document).click(function()` line and then I can only close a drop-down by clicking it's `h3` tag again, or clicking another `h3` tag twice to open a new one and then close them both.

Comment: Why are you using both `jQuery` and `$`?

Comment: It would be best and easier to help for all the SO users with a fiddle

Comment: @JamesCoyle The old dev used jQuery (no idea why) and I am using $ because that's what I understand... Would I be right in assuming I can just replacing jQuery with $?

Comment: Something else could be using `$`. That's usually the only reason to use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: @JamesCoyle interesting... I've replaced all instances of $ with jQuery in my code. It didn't change anything but at least it's consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".open_filter").removeClass("open_filter");
});
```

Is a very bad solution. It triggesrs every time you click anywhere on the site. So also when you click the `h3` tag to open the dropdown. That's why it is closed immediately.

Instead you should check what is clicked when you click the document.

```js
$('.filter-section h3').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('arrow-down');
  if (!$(this).parent().find('.lef-shop-section ul').hasClass('open_filter')) {
    $('.open_filter').removeClass('open_filter');
    $(this).parent().find('.lef-shop-section ul').addClass('open_filter');
  } else {
    $('.open_filter').removeClass('open_filter');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target),
    $ul = $target.closest('.filter-section').find('.lef-shop-section ul');

  if (typeof $ul === "undefined" || !$ul.hasClass('open_filter')) {
    $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
    $('.open_filter').removeClass('open_filter');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.filter-section .lef-shop-section ul {
  display: none;
}

.filter-section .lef-shop-section ul.open_filter {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-section">
  <h3>Click me to open dropdown, clcik anywhere else to close it</h3>
  <div class="lef-shop-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Position 1</li>
      <li>Position 2</li>
      <li>Position 3</li>
      <li>Position 4</li>
      <li>Position 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter-section">
  <h3>Click me to open dropdown, clcik anywhere else to close it</h3>
  <div class="lef-shop-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Position 1</li>
      <li>Position 2</li>
      <li>Position 3</li>
      <li>Position 4</li>
      <li>Position 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. The result is the same as the original problem, I can open multiple drop-downs without any of them closing when another is opened and clicking outside of the dropdown still doesn't close it.

Comment: Okay, then if you could add to your post the fiddle with the reproduced problem taht would be very helpful.

Comment: You're right. Apparently the `blur` does not work with `h3` tag. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: Unfortunately, either because it's built on Wordpress or because I'm a moron, I've been unable to replicate it on jsfiddle, likely because there are plenty of classes and functions being pulled in from various .php files.

Comment: @ConnorHandley take a look now

Comment: Wow, thanks, it almost works! The only issue is that it only closes if I click on another object, but clicking whitespace on the page doesn't seem to work. Can I privately send you the page so you can take a look?

Comment: @ConnorHandley My bad, I just updated an answer. It should work as charm now.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
I had to make this change to the code: 
`if (!$(this).parent().find('.lef-shop-section ul').hasClass('open_filter')) {
  $('.open_filter').removeClass('open_filter');
  $(this).parent().find('.lef-shop-section ul').addClass('open_filter');
   }`
to stop the drop-downs stacking but now it is perfect!
Thanks again :)

Comment: Right, I missed that. I'll update my answer if anyone else will have similar problem